# Realized and Unrealized Profit and Loss

Tags: quant-trading-strategies, trading, algorithmic-trading, quants, trading-systems

https://www.tradingtechnologies.com/xtrader-help/fix-adapter-reference/pl-calculation-algorithm/understanding-pl-calculations/

What I want to know is, after Scenario 4 in this article how does the Realized PnL, Opening Price, Unrealized PnL behave now that direction has changed!

Edit: I have figured out how to deal with the scenario when the opening position is >=0, however, I wish to know what happens after Scenario 4 of this article where-in during the next fill the opening position will <0, how does the different factors behave then.

Comment: Same question again?

Comment: Hey, actually this is kind of a different one built on the earlier one. I have made some progress using this article. And would like to build upon it further if I can close out scenario 4. Would be great if you could give the article a read. It has been presented in a lucid and concise way too. Thank you so much for your help earlier!

Comment: Can you please organise all of this into one question? I can do it too but I think you can do a better job than I can.

Comment: Hi Bob, I didn't quite get what you meant by organising into one question. Can you please clarify it.

Comment: You have made three posts which are very similar. Please edit one of your post to reflect your current state of knowledge and the question you have now. Then delete the other two.

Comment: Okay Bob, sure I will do that right away!

Comment: Done Bob, also just another question @noob2 referred me to, I hope it helps anyone coming in here: https://quant.stackexchange.com/questions/36505/calculate-day-to-day-change-in-value-of-open-position/36517#36517

Comment: Thank you for your quick response.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the question is so nuanced as to be non-generalistic and the supplied self-answer is programmatic in nature

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I finally got the required answer to my problem. I'm sharing the code in Python 3 in case it helps anyone struggling with a similar problem.

[Running Profit and Loss in Python 3](https://github.com/anirbansaha96/AI-ML-Playground/blob/master/TradesRunningProfitAndLoss.py)

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
dataset=pd.read_csv('trades.txt',delimiter= ' ');

#Initialising Variables to be used throughout the program
position=0;
averageopenprice=0;
pnlunrealized=0;
pnlrealized=0;
pnltotal=0;

#Inserting Columns into the dataset to visualise the working in a better way
dataset.insert(2,'Position',np.zeros(len(dataset.index)));
dataset.insert(3,'Average Open Price',np.zeros(len(dataset.index)));
dataset.insert(4,'PnL Unrealized',np.zeros(len(dataset.index)));
dataset.insert(5,'PnL Realized',np.zeros(len(dataset.index)));
dataset.insert(6,'PnL Total',np.zeros(len(dataset.index)));

#Algorithm Begins
for i in range(0,len(dataset.index)):
    qty=dataset.iat[i,0]; #This will help in writing more legible codes
    price=dataset.iat[i,1];
    if position==0:
        position=qty;
        averageopenprice=price;
        pnlrealized=pnlrealized;
        pnlunrealized=0;
        pnltotal=pnlrealized+pnlunrealized;
    elif position>0:
        if qty>0:
            averageopenprice=(position*averageopenprice+qty*price)/(position+qty);
            position+=qty;
            pnlrealized=pnlrealized;
            pnlunrealized=(price-averageopenprice)*position;
            pnltotal=pnlrealized+pnlunrealized;
        elif qty<0:
            if abs(qty)<position:
                averageopenprice=averageopenprice;
                pnlrealized+=(price-averageopenprice)*abs(qty);
                position+=qty;
                pnlunrealized=(price-averageopenprice)*position;
                pnltotal=pnlrealized+pnlunrealized;
            elif abs(qty)==position:
                pnlrealized+=(price-averageopenprice)*abs(qty);
                position=0;
                averageopenprice=0;
                pnlunrealized=0;
                pnltotal=pnlrealized+pnlunrealized;
            elif abs(qty)>position:
                pnlrealized+=(price-averageopenprice)*position;
                position+=qty;
                averageopenprice=price;
                pnlunrealized=(price-averageopenprice)*position;
                pnltotal=pnlrealized+pnlunrealized;
    elif position<0:
        if qty<0:
            averageopenprice=(abs(position)*averageopenprice+abs(qty)*price)/(abs(position+qty));
            position+=qty;
            pnlrealized=pnlrealized;
            pnlunrealized=(averageopenprice-price)*abs(position);
            pnltotal=pnlrealized+pnlunrealized;
        elif qty>0:
            if qty<abs(position):
                averageopenprice=averageopenprice;
                pnlrealized=(averageopenprice-price)*qty;
                position+=qty;
                pnlunrealized=(averageopenprice-price)*abs(position);
                pnltotal=pnlrealized+pnlunrealized;
            elif qty==abs(position):
                pnlrealized+=(averageopenprice-price)*qty;
                position=0;
                averageopenprice=0;
                pnlunrealized=0;
                pnltotal=pnlrealized+pnlunrealized;
            elif qty>abs(position):
                pnlrealized+=(averageopenprice-price)*abs(position);
                position+=qty;
                averageopenprice=price;
                pnlunrealized=0;
                pnltotal=pnlrealized+pnlunrealized;
    dataset.iat[i,2]=position;
    dataset.iat[i,3]=averageopenprice;
    dataset.iat[i,4]=pnlunrealized;
    dataset.iat[i,5]=pnlrealized;
    dataset.iat[i,6]=pnltotal;


output=dataset[['qty','price','PnL Realized','PnL Unrealized','PnL Total']];
```